# Access instagram photos user tagged in

Tags: tags, instagram

I was wondering if you can access photos that the authenticated user has been tagged in via the instagram api.

I understand from their documentation that you can access a variety of end points for the user, including "user/user-id" (which says you can get "basic information about the user"), as well as the user's feed, most recent media, recently liked photos, and search for a photo, but I don't see the photos tagged with the user.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: currently there is no API to get this

Comment: @krisrak thank you for the confirmation.